# Change message body before sending in outlook 365

Tags: visual-studio-2015, outlook, office365, outlook-addin

It possible to change message body (e.g. add some text at the end) on send button clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 365? There is no such thing. Do you mean Outlook 2016 (desktop app)? Or Outlook Web App?

In the former case, trap the `Application.ItemSend` event and modify the message passed as the parameter.

In the latter case, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Oh, sorry I mean Office 365 Outlook (Web App)

Comment: Can't do anything like that from a web addin, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Office.js API currently doesn't support events. There are a lot of requests for monitoring "onSend" event. You may up vote it over here: [officespdev.uservoice.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10964871-add-itemsend-event-so-add-in-can-cancel-email).

Meanwhile you may need to consider re-design your application to change message body at the time of add-in invocation by user. To manipulate with the body of the message Office.js API provides plenty of functions: [Office.context.mailbox.item.body](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Body.html)

**EDIT:**

[On send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins) was implemented with lots of limitation, but at least it's there. [Outlook add-in on send code sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) is available as well.