# How to send signed and encrypted email in Outlook modern add-in

Tags: typescript, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, add-in

I am trying to implement the feature for sending signed and encrypted email (S/MIME) in Office.js. I have found an article [[link]](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dvespa/2009/03/16/how-to-sign-or-encrypt-a-message-programmatically-from-oom/) implemented using VB about that, I tried to convert the program, but I couldn't do it because Office.js API doesn't support Property accessor that is able to get and set MAPI properties.

```
Const PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003"
Dim mi As MailItem
Set mi = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Dim prop As Long

prop = CLng(mi.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS))
ulFlags = ulFlags Or &H1 ' SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED
ulFlags = ulFlags Or &H2 ' SECFLAG_SIGNED
mi.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, ulFlags
Set mi = Nothing
```

I tried to implement using EWS, it also doesn't work. 0x6E010003 might be Property Id and Property Type (0x0003 means unsigned long).

```
<t:SetItemField>
<t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Common" PropertyId="28161" PropertyType="Integer" />
<t:Message>
    <t:ExtendedProperty>
        <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Common" PropertyId="28161" PropertyType="Integer" />
        <t:Value>3</t:Value>
    </t:ExtendedProperty>
</t:Message>
```

Could someone have the solution to do this?

Comment: Even if you could set these prosperities, it would not work - the properties are really just flags to tell the Windows Outlook client to encrypt the message. It would not work in any other environment (OWA, iOS, Android, Mac).

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Is there a way to set the flags of a properties using EWS?

Comment: I think you are missing my point - Outlook (the desktop version) needs to see that property when its internal equivalent of ItemSend is firing.  Setting the property with EWS will not help with that.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko This means that I can implement signed and encrypted email programmatically by converting the flags of the properties received when ItemSend is firing. Furthermore, since Office modern add-in doesn't support ItemSend event, It is impossible to implement the functionality. Is that right?

Comment: Send event is available in office.js api: [Change message body before sending in outlook 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095378/change-message-body-before-sending-in-outlook-365/43096527#43096527). You also able to set extended property via EWS request. What @DmitryStreblechenko is trying to tell you is this particular property doesn't mean anything for Exchange. This is just the flag. Encrypting and signing operations has to be done at Outlook level. Short answer is You cannot sign and encrypt message by using Office.js API and/or EWS.

Comment: I totally understood. Thank you all.